# iOS Social framework getting facebook account using facebook application

Tags: ios, objective-c, social-framework

I can get facebook account from the settings, but not from the facebook application. Is there any way to get facebook account from installed facebook application without using facebook SDK?

Answer (score 1):

To get Facebook account form app you need to set permissions:

```
[self authorizeWithFBAppAuth:YES safariAuth:YES];
```

in this method:

```
- (void)authorize:(NSArray *)permissions delegate:(id<FBSessionDelegate>)delegate
```

Comment: Is there any way to have facebook sdk to login using native login(getting facebook account from phone settings)?

Comment: You can use `Social` and `Account` Framework to get Facebook account without using `Facebook SDK`. 
I think, for this you need to have a Facebook app in your device.

Comment: also first finalize from where you want the account details - From the Facebook app or From Setting? your question and comments confusing more.

Comment: I was thinking using both... But now I guess I will focus on social and account framework, request user to sign in to settings if he/she is not. Thanks for the reply!